# fastest way to compare differences in the keys of two configuration files (associative arrays)

Tags: bash, awk

Having two files written in the form of associative array (key=value) like:

file A:

```
banana=yellow
kiwi=green
tomato=red
```

file B:

```
banana=dislike
tomato=like
pear=like
```

I would like to know the best approach (in term of speed) to compare their keys:

A against B:

```
kiwi=green
```

B against A

```
pear=like
```

bidirectional

```
kiwi=green
pear=like
```

I would prefer not to use loops as those files can be huge.

Comment: You got any more specific information about your files? When you say "huge", do you have a "ballpark" figure for that? How "long" might the records be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

B against A

```
awk -F'=' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}!($1 in a)' A B
```

A against B

```
awk -F'=' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$0;next}!($1 in a)' B A
```

bidirectional

```
awk -F'=' '{a[$1]++;v[$1]=$0}END{for(i in a)if(a[i]==1)print v[i]}' A B
```

all not tested, let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: Perfect thanks! I knew the answer was 'awk', unluckily I still cannot manage to use it properly. It's so powerful ...

Comment: yes it is powerful, but powerful tools made one lazy... glad to help.

Comment: @LucaBorrione you are free to choose the best solution you think. but personally I think my answer would be faster/better than the accepted one, particularly for big files. that join/sort/sort will have 3 processes started, sort twice and join once.  awk solution doesn't need to sort at all. and only one process. anyway, important is you found the solution here at SO.

Comment: I just ended to play a while with the given solutions: at first sight it seems join a good idea, but it gave me problems with my real data as I can have special characters and symbols as keys like '_' (no problem with awk) and I noticed differences in term of speed too using my big files .. so thank for pointing it out! Twice accepted :)

Comment: That's a "loop" in "biderectional" :-)

Comment: @BillWoodger have you read codes of Sort cmd? it uses mergesort, is there a loop in mergesort implementation?

Comment: +1 for the solutions. You can just do `a[$1]` instead of `a[$1]=$0` though. Should save some memory, don't know if that'd affect time or not.

Comment: @EdMorton you are right, I didn't notice that I wrote a[]=$0... I thought a[x] might be used later maybe... `=$0` is not needed. but I just leave the answer there..

Answer (score 6):

Using `join`:

A against B:

```
$ join -t= -j 1 -v 1 <(sort fileA) <(sort fileB) 
kiwi=green
```

B against A:

```
$ join -t= -j 1 -v 2 <(sort fileA) <(sort fileB) 
pear=like
```

Bi directional:

```
$ join -t= -j 1 -v 1 -v 2 <(sort fileA) <(sort fileB) 
kiwi=green
pear=like
```

Comment: +1 but I'd used the option `--nocheck-order` instead of `sort`.

Comment: My version of `join` doesn't have that option: `join (coreutils) 5.2.1`

Comment: Ah okay, I'm running `GNU coreutils 8.15`.

Comment: It's working great! Thanks ... I'm not used to use 'join' thanks for teaching

Answer (score 0):

I like dogbane's answer, but will submit my crummy solution using grep and cut:

```
grep -v -f <(for key in $(cut -d '=' -f 1 fileA); do echo "^$key="; done) fileB
```